# How to specify types with customUseFetch in Nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I believe you can use Nuxt3's useFetch as follows:

```
const { data: res } = useFetch<ExType>("api_url here")
```

However, to intercept requests and other operations with useFetch, I am using a wrapped version called customUseFetch, as shown below:

```
export const customUseFetch = (url: string, options?: FetchOptions<unknown>) => {
  return useFetch(url, {
    ...options,
    async onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
      console.log('[fetch response]')
    },
    async onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
      console.log('[fetch response error]')
    },

    async onRequest({ request, options }) {
      console.log('[fetch request]')
    },
    async onRequestError({ request, options, error }) {
      console.log('[fetch request error]')
    }
  })
}
```

How can I modify customUseFetch to allow specifying types in the same way as useFetch, as shown below?

```
const { data: res } = customUseFetch<ExType>("api_url here")
```

I simply tried like below, but this cause a type error at the second arg of useFetch ...

```
const customUseFetch = <T>(url: string, options?: FetchOptions<T>) => {
  return useFetch<T>(url, { ・・・
```

I would greatly appreciate any help from someone who knows. Thank you!"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a composable called `useCustomFetch` inside the composable you can have export `customFetch` function like this

We use `ofetch` to achieve this, it comes with nuxt

```
import { ofetch } from 'ofetch'
import type { FetchOptions } from 'ofetch'

const config = useRuntimeConfig()

export const BE_URL = config.public.baseUrl // base url

/**
 * Custom ofetch wrapper for ehsat app
 * @param url
 * @param options
 * @returns Promise<T>
 */
export function customFetch<T>(url: string, options?: FetchOptions | undefined): Promise<T> {
  const token = useAccessToken() // if you have an access token
  const customFetch = ofetch.create({ baseURL: BE_URL })
  return customFetch(url, {
    ...options,
    headers: {
      ...options?.headers,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token.value}`,
    },
    credentials: 'include', 
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It appears that the return type of customFetch is 'any.' 
Can we receive the type of 'result' as Promise<T> ? 
Say I define result like this . const result = customFetch(url, ...) I'd like to get as type of result as Promise<T> .

Comment: Or you mean you can replace useFetch that inside of my customUseFetch with customFetch<T> ??